# if user is already logged-in and clicked on share button in wesite facebook asking log-in credentials in IE8 ..!

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using javascript SDK to implement feed functionality. Here is my problem, if user is logged-in and clicked on share button facebook asking log-in credentials in IE8 . In IE9 working fine

i am using this code

```
FB.init({appId: "416595358373189",show_error:true, status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

    function callback(response) 
{

    }
```

Comment: You are using the `c#` and the `java` SDK in javascript? think not?

Comment: iam using the above javascript in my page

Comment: Ok, I meant "why did you tag it with those tags", but nevermind.

Comment: i got this code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: this is the first question i'm posting . so that i confused . If you have solution plese let me know